# Reduce an array of objects and return all the original properties of the object

Tags: javascript, reduce

I have an array of objects with 4 properties each object, like this:

```
let arr = [
{name: john, lastName: smith, counter:1, city: New York}
{name: john, lastName: smith, counter:1, city: New York}
{name: emilio, lastName: kouri, counter:1, city: euy}
{name: john, lastName: smith, counter:1, city: New York}
]
```

I want to reduce it for it to return this (sum the counter)

```
[{name: emilio, lastName: kouri, counter:1, city: euy}
{name: john, lastName: smith, counter:3, city: New York}]
```

This is the code im using right now, and it reduces it correctly but only returns [counter, name], I want it to return all four properties of each object, how can it be done?

```
  let counts = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    let count = prev.get(curr.name) || 0;

      prev.set(curr.name, curr.counter + count);
        return prev;
    }, new Map());


      let reducedObjArr = [...counts].map(([key, value]) => {
        return {key, value}
      })
    console.log('reducido',reducedObjArr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one `reduce` statement with no nested `map` statements:

```js
let arr = [{
  name: "john",
  lastName: "smith",
  counter: 1,
  city: "New York"
}, {
  name: "john",
  lastName: "smith",
  counter: 1,
  city: "New York"
}, {
  name: "emilio",
  lastName: "kouri",
  counter: 1,
  city: "euy"
}, {
  name: "john",
  lastName: "smith",
  counter: 1,
  city: "New York"
}];

let counts = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc.some(({ name }) => name == curr.name)) {
    acc.push(curr);
  } else {
    acc.find(({ name }) => name == curr.name).counter++;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(counts);
```

Comment: No problem whatsoever @SvenBrodersen.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a copy of the object with a count of zero and increment this object and set this object.

```js
let arr = [{ name: 'john', lastName: 'smith', counter: 1, city: 'New York' }, { name: 'john', lastName: 'smith', counter: 1, city: 'New York' }, { name: 'emilio', lastName: 'kouri', counter: 1, city: 'euy' }, { name: 'john', lastName: 'smith', counter: 1, city: 'New York' }];

let counts = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    let item = prev.get(curr.name) || Object.assign({}, curr, { counter: 0 });
    item.counter += curr.counter;
    return prev.set(curr.name, item);
}, new Map);

let reducedObjArr = [...counts.values()]

console.log('reducido', reducedObjArr);
```